# Which companies offer helicopter tours of the Grand Canyon from Las Vegas?

Tags: usa, tours, las-vegas, grand-canyon, helicopters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [View the Grand Canyon by helicopter - is it real?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/515/view-the-grand-canyon-by-helicopter-is-it-real)

Our family of 5 is going to Las Vegas for the first time and we'd like to see the Grand Canyon.  What tours by air are available?